# Verify: Prove the Continuous Extension Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

Let $A$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.  Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ if and only if it is possible to construct $\hat f: \bar A \to \mathbb{R}$ as a continuous extension of $f$ to $\bar A$ (the closure of $A$).

*Note: Proofs of the Continuous Extension Theorem are readily available.  This question asks to critique* my *proof as well as several questions below.*

**Lemma:** Let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous, and let $(x_n) \in A$ converge to $x$ (not necessarily in $A$).  Then $(f(x_n))$ converges.  Moreover, if $(x'_n) \in A$ converges to $x$, then $(f(x'_n))$ converges to the limit of $(f(x_n))$.

Proof: Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x_n - x_m| < \delta \implies |f(x_n) - f(x_m)| < \varepsilon$.  Additionally, since $(x_n)$ converges, it is a Cauchy sequene, and there exists $N$ such that for all $n, m \geq N, |x_n - x_m| < \delta$, so that $|f(x_n) - f(x_m)| < \varepsilon$.  Thus, $(f(x_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges.

Suppose $(x'_n) \in A$ also converges to $x$.  Then $|x_n - x'_n| \to 0$, and since $f$ is uniformly continuous, $|f(x_n) - f(x'_n)| \to 0$, so $\lim f(x'_n) = \lim f(x_n)$.

**Main Proof:** Clearly $\bar A$ is compact, and so if continuous $\hat f$ exists, then $\hat f$ as well as its restriction $f$ are uniformly continuous.  We now prove the converse (that if $f$ is uniformly continuous, we can extend it to continuous $\hat f: \bar A \to \mathbb{R}$) by constructing $\hat f$ as follows.

As an extension of $f$, $\hat f(x) := f(x)$ for all $x \in A$.  Recall that for all $x \in \bar A$, either $x \in A$ or $x$ is a limit point of $A$.  Therefore, for any $x$ in $\bar A$ but not in $A$, we can construct a sequence $(x_n) \in A$ converging to $x$.  By the lemma, $f(x_n)$ will converge to same limit for all such sequences, and so we define $\hat f(x) = \lim f(x_n)$.

Observe that $\hat f$ is continuous, since for any $(x_n) \in \bar A$ converging to $x$, $\lim \hat f(x_n) = \lim f(x_n) = \hat f(x)$ by construction.

---

### Discussion

1. Is the proof correct and rigorous?
2. Is it well written? How can the exposition be improved?
3. This proof is for any bounded set $A$ and its closure.  I've seen the theorem presented only for open intervals, but I believe, as written, it applies to all bounded sets.  Am I right?
4. The lemma asserts not only that $(f(x_n))$ converges, but that it does so to the same limit for all $(x_n) \to x$.  I believe this part is necessary and sufficient to establish continuity of $\hat f$.  Am I correct?
5. Using #4, I encapsulated most of the complexity into the lemma, with the main proof following almost immediately.  Does this structure clarify the exposition?
6. The lemma holds only for *uniformly* continuous functions, since $(x_n)$ may converge to a limit outside of $A$.  However, if $A$ is closed, a similar property holds for *any* continuous function:  Since $(x_n) \in A \to x \in A$, then $(f(x_n)) \to f(x)$.  Thus, continuous functions on closed domains are [Cauchy-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function).  Is this of significance?

Comment: The statement itself is awkward: you don't need $A$ to be bounded to extend $f.$

Comment: @AnneBauval If $A$ is not bounded, the statement is not true! E.g. If $A = \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^2$ then construct $\hat f: \bar A \to \mathbb{R} = f$, yet $f$ is not uniformly continuous.  The proof likewise relies on $\bar A$ being compact, which is only true if $A$ is bounded.

Comment: This does not contradict my comment, which concerns the "only if" part.

Comment: The proof of the first part of your lemma could be shortened by just saying "any uniformly continuous map sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences". The second part could be proved in a more elegant way, using the 1st part instead of re-using the uniform continuity : if $x'_n\to x$ then the sequence $(x_1,x'_1,x_2,x'_2,\dots)$ also converges to $x$ hence (by the first part) its image by $f$ converges, which proves that the two sequences $(f(x_n))$ and $(f(x'_n))$ have the same limit.

Comment: In the definition of $\hat f(x),$ it is useless to treat first separately the case $x\in A.$ Any element of $\bar A$ (be it in $A$ or not) is the limit of a sequence of elements of $A.$

Comment: You did not prove correctly the continuity of $\hat f$: for your sequence "$(x_n)\in\bar A$", $f(x_n)$ is not defined if $x_n\notin A.$

Comment: @AnneBauval This is great feedback! I want to understand it all, and, as is, I understand part, but not all of it.  Would you be able to collect your feedback into a consolidated answer, and elaborate a bit?

Comment: Glad it pleased you but I cannot copy-paste it as an answer, because I did not (and don't intend to) adress all of your 6 points. But I can detail in comments what you don't understand. Take your time, I am going to sleep ;-)

Comment: @AnneBauval 1. "You did not prove correctly the continuity..." Great catch!  I am working to rectify this.  

2. "The proof of the first part of your lemma could be shortened by just saying 'any uniformly continuous map sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences'."  The lemma itself is proving that uniformly continuous maps send Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.  I am not starting with that result but proving it. Does that address your concern?

3. "The statement is awkward... concerns the 'only if' part".  I still do not follow this.

Comment: You can replace your incorrect proof of the continuity of $\bar f$ as follows: Let $y\in\bar A.$ If $\bar f$ was discontinuous at $y$ then there would exist $r>0$ and a sequence $(y_n)_n$ in $\bar A$ converging to $y,$ such that $|\bar f(y_{2n-1})-\bar f(y_{2n})|>r$ for all $n.$ Now for each $n$ take $x_n\in A$ such that $|x_n-y_n|<1/n$ and $|f(x_n)-\bar f(y_n)|<r/3.$  So $|f(x_{2n-1})-f(x_{2n})|>r/3$ for each $n.$ But  then $(x_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence of members of $A$ such that $(f(x_n))_n$ does not converge, contrary to your Lemma.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I included a simpler proof in my answer 2 hours before your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal of improvement, to "consolidate" my comments. (Against my taste, I stay with numerical functions, to respect your choice.)

Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb R.$

**Definition** A map $f:A\to\Bbb R$ is:

- uniformly continuous if [...]
- Cauchy-continous if [...]

**Three obvious remarks**

R1) Uniform continuity and Cauchy-continuity are preserved by restriction.

R2) Any uniformly continuous function is Cauchy-continuous.

R3) Any Cauchy-continuous function is continuous.

The converse of R2 and R3 are false [examples
...] but:

[**Heine-Cantor theorem**...]

**Two more obvious remarks**

R4) Any continuous function on a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ is Cauchy-continuous (this may be used to certify that the extension $\hat f$ of the theorem below is not only continuous but Cauchy-continuous).

R5) (not so interesting, from my point of view) As a consequence of Heine-Cantor theorem and of R1, if $A$ is bounded and $f$ extends to a continous map $\hat f:\bar A\to\Bbb R,$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

We shall now state a "strong converse" of R5, which does not require $A$ to be bounded.

**Continuous extension theorem** Let $f:A\to\Bbb R$ be Cauchy-continuous. Then, $f$ admits a continuous extension $\hat f:\bar A\to\Bbb R.$

**Proof**

Let $x\in\bar A.$ For any sequence $(a_n)$ of elements of $A$ converging to $x,$ $(f(a_n))$ is a Cauchy sequence by R2, hence admits a limit $y.$ Moreover, $y$ does not depend on the choice of $(a_n)$ because if $(a'_n)$ is another such sequence, then $(a_1,a'_1,a_2,a'_2,\dots)$ also is, hence (by what we just showed) its image by $f$ admits a limit, which proves that $(f(a'_n))$ has the same limit $y$ as $(f(a_n)).$ This allow us to define $\hat f(x)$ as being this common limit $y.$

Note that $\hat f$ is an extension of $f$ (if $x\in A$, we may apply the definition of $\hat f(x)$ with the constant sequence $a_n=x$).

Let us now prove that $\hat f$ is continuous. Let $(x_n)$ be a converging sequence in $\bar A,$ and $x$ be its limit. For each $n\in\Bbb N,$ by definition of $\hat f(x_n),$ there exists an element $a_n\in A$ such that $|x_n-a_n|$ and $|\hat f(x_n)-f(a_n)|$ are both $<\frac1n.$ Using such a sequence $(a_n)$, we deduce: $\hat f(x)=\lim f(a_n)=\lim\hat f(x_n).$

Comment: Fantastic! 1. It seems to me you are aiming for a style found in an article or paper, which starts from the ground up (definitions), builds towards interesting results, and includes discussion of interest along the way, as opposed to the style I used, which was more of a direct answer to a question, similar to how you'd find in homework.  Is that correct?

Comment: 2. You state that R2 is "obvious." Intuitively, it is not obvious, at least to me, that continuous functions may not be Cauchy-continuous but uniformly continuous functions are.  By "obvious," do you mean that the proof follows mechanically from $\varepsilon \delta$ manipulations (even if those manipulations aren't trivial)? Why else do you consider it "obvious"?

Comment: 1. I was more aiming for a style of a lecture. 2. By "obvious" I mean: which can be proved mentally while driving a car. This applies to R2 (it is the first sentence of your proof of your lemma). It is hardly more difficult to find a continuous function which is not Cauchy-continuous.